# Good practice while creating schema in Hibernate application

Tags: java, database, hibernate

This might seem to be a very basic question but what is usually a good practice for creating database schema while using Hibernate application (especially while creating an application from scratch).

Although we can create it using hibernate by using "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create" property but should it be preferred over creating schema using DB administration applications like PL/SQL developer.

Though we can create partitions, indexes and sequences using PL/SQL Developer but is it also possible to do same using hibernate as well. Even if so, is it a good practice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `create` works only one time and not for extending databases, `drop-and-create` may destroy your production data - most people use `create` as initial setup and migrate production databases via third party products (manually, Flyway, Liquibase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate generates DDL statements by analysing your annotations or `<class>` and `<database-object>` definitions in the XML files, it does not take your queries into account. Anyways, it is performance-wise enough for many developers who just develop big software in small chunks and easy to put into automation (e.g. in testing).

Normally one should define partitions and indexes in a production (or production-like) environment after seeing the nature of the data and queries on the data.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Hibernate recommends manual (assisted whit version control system) administration of the schema for production environments.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-schema